# Next.js build process: static pages not generated - deployment fails

Tags: javascript, deployment, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my first next.js project on vercel. Locally everything is working.

**My problem:** When deploying (command: next build) the web app I get the message "Generating static sites (0/2000)" and then nothing happens. The deployment is cancelled after 1h (time expiration).

The problem is somewhere in the (simplified) code below. Here's why: when I deploy the project without the part that follows after **const content** the deployment is successful - so basically instead of having singleProductResponse AND contentResponse as props, I only have singleProductResponse..

I'm a little stuck and don't know how to solve this. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!!

```
const Item = ({ singleProductResponse, contentResponse }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.section}>
      <Overview
        singleProductResponse={singleProductResponse}
        contentResponse={contentResponse}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const itemResponse = await knex("Items");

  const paths = itemResponse.map((product) => ({
    params: {
      brand: product.brand,
      item: product.item,
    },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  try {
    const itemData = await knex("Items").where(
      "item",
      "like",
      `${params.item}`
    );
    const singleProductResponse = itemData[0];

   //!!!!!!!!!when leaving the following part out: deployment is successful!!!!!!!!!!!!
    const content = itemData[0].contentList;
    const splitContent = content.split(", ");
    const contentArray =
      typeof splitContent === "string"
        ? [splitContent]
        : splitContent;
    const result = await knex("Cos")
      .leftJoin("Actives", "Cos.content", "ilike", "Actives.content")
      .leftJoin("Alcohol", "Cos.content", "ilike", "Alcohol.content")
      .column([
        "Cos.content",
        "function",
        "translationPlant",
        "categoryAlcohol",
      ])
      .where((qb) => {
        contentArray.forEach((word) => {
          qb.orWhere("Cos.content", word);
        });
        return qb;
      });

    return {
      props: { singleProductResponse, contentResponse },
      revalidate: 1,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
After digging deeper: I think the problem is that the part after `const  content` is too slow in building process.

When running `next build`, as well as when deploying on vercel the building process stops after approx. 1h. I suppose this is because of the limit of 45min for building process.

The last message I get is "Generating static pages (1000/2000)" (in vercel and locally) and "Build failed" (vercel). I don't get any other error-messages (also not in the catch block).

I've already tried to optimize the part after `const content` (each table has an index (clustered indexes -> primary keys), I've redesigned the tables (only 4 tables to join, instead of 6), eliminated everything unnecessary in the query and checked that the database (postgres hosted on heroku - hobby-basic) is also in the US). The performance is better, but still not enough. Does anyone have some suggestions for improvement? TTFB might be a somehow slow.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when running `next build` locally at all? Do you get anything from the catch's `console.log`?

Comment: Yeah ^ +1 to that. Trying doing `next build && next start` to simulate a production build. If it still isn't working, I would consider contacting Vercel support! (Lee from Vercel here)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I've updated my question. I don't get any additional error-messages. I will contact the vercel support, but before doing that: maybe you have some further improvements? :)